# Can 301 redirects to homepage solve 404 errors in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, 404, crawl-errors

I have a site with a few hundred 404s. I am sure there are no relevant pages to redirect users to so I want to redirect users to homepage.

Will redirecting to homepage be a good strategy compared to displaying a 404 error?

Comment: A good strategy for what?   Preventing errors in the console?   Boosting your site's SEO?   Keeping users engaged?

Answer (score 2):

> Will redirecting to homepage be a good strategy than displaying a 404?

Probably not. Mass redirections to the homepage are likely to be [seen as a soft-404s by the search engines (ie. Google)](https://www.seroundtable.com/301-pages-home-soft-404-22811.html) anyway. And it's confusing for users - they are not seeing the information they expected to see and no indication that something is wrong.

You are better off serving a custom 404 with a meaningful message to your users.

Comment: Assuredly not.   Whether en mass or a single case, Google considers redirects to the home page as "soft 404".